# Add icon in echarts Label

Tags: echarts

In Echarts I would like to add an Icon in label, I have set a base64 image but its empty, when I set a color background it works, this is the code:

[echarts icon label](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-in-cartesian-coordinate-system&code=G4QwTgBGCuB2DOEC8EBMAoUkC2BTE80YuiKGWEAlgMYD2sAQmJQCYDmuyEA5JdiBwBcAemEsQAFxCC-A3MIAOsNgG4ARgVwA2ACwAaSgDUGAeQBKAdwAMAaQDibWgEEXTgHIBlAKoALAKJebK4AwgCark7YwU7hLsG0AAq42NARwQAaDACSAOrpALKu8AAqrgAyfhZ-kQoWsa7pnmZWWU5g8DrUWgCKEWaw3V4AjAxxAB4AVhbAAByhg64ePt5mDIYAEmwMAF6GPizFAGJjh4cAIjrbwXYAzN1uDPC0DACOflYSOtgA1IcMbt1QkMAFIvKwAGysxSsPWAUg8EhsAE9DB4ssCyjpQrQzsMAJxgJFqNj5b60KxsABmwQA1oYyjMnKhDMDKDoEkMFN8XndKQo2ABWMBWUIvdIsABaWXS1D8CWgNx86wkWm2ElQLCReO2ZWEYDKZQk4JmSNQxWg23y22AlNgE1g2xu6RMJjYwSGbDxAoA7MCaWVUCYwN0_dVDmpuuwGN0GIdpj4zOS1G5gTcBTSsnjYEjDtTQh50jd6ME2IZggKzsAzPk7KFgi8vuthKEzt0zuE7IcnBLih4GEixcDcGYcjZtmdtnYWAx0vAzC87JQ1AknOwzmBwTlUGcfCY_J3vgKrJOvCBUMCcqFgOkhjSrBLgjonBY8RIiBMFRLDBYFOszhMWDOHJDCpNxvgsEwLBYGZvm2bYfB8AD0i8NxhGAWAbnWShtmoCQTDOEBikwnQBQkeBwQlGYxgSeA2kObA8WwciBUOUI1FwBI_BALxumoKwQBuLwzCcYpcG9G4rDMG4JlQAVtiRHIPDOLQQGgbB1gYHxvmCNRqGBeAshAMprjYCVhFgEwXhAGYfHSVAshMGwzGAOxDAlPFgUpM5ihbdZUDxMorD8MY7AYG5vWCbYdAldJgAYUIvFCw48RuLJ4EpWMkS4iQJGwM5KDsYIzks7YhhAEBlDAMwJW2HIvEiJEhh0X4BQmYR0g8GlKXyXibjGGxUAmSkvBmNQhnyYQJnyVBvhpNRgQ8ExYBpXBgGgaALDMYQaR8JFwVCAV1hMYAtAuWA8W6dIaS0NwZjALxsCRBRvQ8d0ZhYeB1lgagZnql5wTKBgFGgdFvAYM51gFbBsw3GY6soNxtisQwhmCPEzBAKwbjOBRutwUJsz8Ng3EoCQGAkWAzBYQwsm9F5KAUANKaRYBgWoMpDgSKx4AFYItDGCRulob0GGCcEwBmYclyGGydDKCSsiGIY3BuBg8QsSgQD8CRtn-4BtjYbZ4HC4odC8HIyjcEAckpBJKQtBRqEDGYhjxYDqAsLQEi0CSWDALIrGgLxgTGVAEeGdJsGBQw3G9CYzgFMYrG-bjyx0Mw3HgUIbkpPEJT8CYvGAM4ziBnxgGwLqnGBJwRWgYAygFBRaFwHR0gUeqtBeYQbe-bocm-BubFoaBaBMAs2DJoYcngb16pYBIS0pNRYFgXBKQCMwsloHw1GCNwzmodI7G2MZPo8bYojYGwLB8CUc_q2O3FkvyWHWGkbmKeBPVwSgfAzP-QwEhnAkOsCUZwLDgj8FkLQ-R0i0BsCAboMCwpIjKBuUQ4YFBZDAMIMYbAzgSmgGoaA3wFAvEMGcb0SN4C3AkBYLwNJDjelwLQLIahKSUnoHYHahhYBqFoEpcE6w-pjBeGUHIHxox4mKN6dIlJrbCEOJ6WgbhwRsGNmwIY-14DRHSI4Fg1AWChDsBMMweIZjQFwAoLQwRlE2DGOkYI_USxgFgEMagwQEiHBsBNGwuAfDehpEMMYfgFB-GKD4HI2BtioGgFoHI-RKRgDUCwbANgcg0jMNQOw2B0iHGKL8b4IMnA2GpjSdYpQrJ4mgN0Fe_ZQgKGwH4NwJhKDgxpAoOMZQWC4GVFYb0dgZiqO2JQXEPgnD0GBNsYouQYrAlPF4NQ6wnAzASMAMAAp3FOGgDMQ4AoQChHSakKwvE2DYDAH4YIM8QoSlwGMMW3wF5qCRBIWgxQchnB0krCUdg46hTsOsQw6SWByRuH4GktT0ktJsBKdU4JigSGAJ1SkNhwTUFwGoGwNxDAJG9IYJJ2wPBgGBBIfiOgFE5GEF5YQZhDrehAGcHxLAG6UFgJjFSHg2CyPWN0E0lBgB-G9KEag4IzjT0pItXa-RwTAhANQeAChujQBeO4Q4ExvisNCLmLQ5xhBaEpBMfaYhUBOQlD4SawBKD5H2MCIY4UFAQNQC8aAQx6rbFCFCYQOgZh2FwFkMYYwak0j8GUeAOQ1DenYiwGkwgVZuDMD4Lw8BlGHG9ZQAc1AwAMA8B4NNTh7bHhAN8BgsA_T-NoN0eA1B-GaWoPaHIJgFBDGgOkQWFhDC0HWGMYoNbVIMAlPkfI9CxhDCyIcHIdgQDABsJ2nIOhsxDDODMJisALBuFoNgDwsjDBqByHtZSIAGbAiRFk4o4IFDgjbJsSgqB0g4ysII-A11Ob5HWDkLInR8i0C8MEG44IuxOCyAKceTVgCoG2KPMwpptgJHWNQLIPEaRjE2OsYEGNQjwBjIYMmwQFDwHyAoIkYAbDdAFGUSgwgLBEomDBJGhw-buNlAwHQZx-hIgSD4WA6QshuFwIyCI3hDDmBsLzUIWQshIG4JgcAVA6CwFXMALgvB-BCFEOIKQMhVPyCUKoDQ8BtD6CMKYSwtgHDOFcJ4XwAQghxHqJEaI9R4hJBSGkTIuQChFFKC4CoVQah1AiE4RoHhmitHaJ0HofQBjDFGE4ZxUxZjzHqi4PsKw1ibAYGMPYbgjhZfOOJboKQcZNKcHYM4iH8jBKsF4AUtAdAgGQzYaA25qBuDKC8M4xgfyUAsE5MYwI2DiZMDcDwChbiUBpGwNQoRoB-D8GYQ4tBG1lC1moLwToJjwDKGcF49MPA5GBMAHQNIEj0ysDSJEZwdo5B8FIMoEx4PfC0DMPEcdgAsDqfIBIEoyhtq0N6PEeIsZeh1nBG4Oc_AsCcH4dIEwxg5ged6HIDBqBsBMGMZ8Zw2Dju6AEPwlIhgeFoH4G43iwAQZaWYSgEwQBjDcGALQ3xXwWG6IcIWkY7BpQkGYFbqB1gWBmNGHwjIxHPhyKGygApuj5G9IRm4wI8SHAQgkNgPhDhgAuFoFgJwnBnDbaOMwOgchFTsHiFOZxYAzFgKxvESIPlLsuqgMYIAdDILxGfUQFhXcJGo9AcE_BTfAB8GUCUEw_A5E9HdSDoQncSASKEIFwB9X7NnKgUnTd1iRoFDG8H0YVpmDg3kCQagygeC0EiHw68RXby0GoYFO8nDC_yMAJw1ptfCCGJQLIqwtC0G1YYUaG10hWCXIUHIThgC0EwkRvE1y7ByppjYBQZLUA0m9GwawbBGVOC0HiUpEoaDfB8EMOwYwBTuSV2YT1LCzAeGoN6AtWGQC0DACYFglBtuTyNDYGYWgQ03FwGgDYHWEKjcUYVIReCRHSElw42wHj3IUMyRAAOoGECnBeBmARQlA8GBGWgYFMmAAsHtSRG6AsCdieTGDAHww8hmHXS1BMDxBYAeielGwImEFwDNGKR0DYC-AsCRH9QUFCBJmEgmGBGEAlAUBmBeAFFtlgCyG2HlVVHeC8DAB0DxFWlwG6DhxpAMkoHWBbWmRVAWWwAlEOjYGgDOCRAKhMGBAYG9H6znlVW6B0BbUBgUG0D7ngB2GwC8HiQkAJ1oFQGCBMDsA8HBCTjTAsFtim2MHgBYDKyRAmBMF-isCsDUW-FjgrzGB8DGF2RuFwW-ApFgBiNwGVisEB29GoHWw8BAFwGCGBEOHRBYAsALXyBmBmB0mBD_WhFwFfB8CyFCAZ0MAmD73yHrDmm9BoHlXWHkKGHWFoE1BwTcF3y0B-BpAKIIMMGoBxWAG6ANh2l4x8VCAkDACwJpApR62oHgx8BjBmG53lRuGoB8CnxYCsAXmgGKC0AtWwGVWt0iR5mEFoAkOAAe1PTAG2AYFoBmB-hjQjVQC8ALh4ScGEGBCCS0BmwSCX0pB8B0BYAKLGEpFCDMDCBMCRBsAmUoEoByAU2wEdjuCOjMBsC7nCTKEnBuG2C8FgEuUMHA2BHyXSBsIlGBCyA8CGBsB9QYGKFaP9jcAFC8AlBFRpFCAcRMEOEoDMBpnyByDuG9EpBeF4irAGyzSRG2G-GoB5A8BmFklnVPWBFCEMGEFiWxWAHBHgDACkJmBAhdJpByHBAsHJHESRG9CsGojsHBCiUjFCAYC8DxEpGEB8DsA6zGEaX8HyHgGwFMnXTjBsBjOVCRC0DYDJDUR8AYGgGEloDwjWzp2KFsPSBJ2XDODUgSFGSWLYByFqNajMCGGFlKzgOwFuHGj_wV2-CLGCJb07KBlGL9SRAsASGpxMBaDCTxBsBeFoGEBMBpH9GXOgAFCREDIlGoAUCA2NIkAkI4mf1QGEFXG8BeAxFgBTAYAsDMheCyCNXSASFgErhAGA0OH20hh8CpHyGKBAELnWAqDUDfO6BMAFDcBlQFByGoBAFPW2GcErXagECNQiWEEXmpRTnSC0HBAFBxJ0EMDsH5jGDUGyIImQtwFwFjTOFIsIO6GCAkDMQSAdOiiGB8E4TsOMjADTR0D5zhFwHbGEACHpCTQLX_ngBeGzXzHSGWSyEih0AmCGEGlQBVwFGWHWEpFwC8AmDKBDg8HyDUDsDMC0AUBuDcFfFQGoAlBsBpGBC0C8G9BgRlOBGBB8HBFwDsBMGgDsC8FoE7WCAlGAu9DNEQ2mJlOKAUBlUkMhW3LYD2iyFgC0GBABiyCrRVXnyYv_WvmBAmFCGtAlEpD5yFh8CglCAmB8CsCRDYG6BsG-C8GSwmEoBmGKDAHjg7mfgFHApAB_OwAPgiXmyyEoCsBeA8ElQ8GgDaVu0oDUnAB_zlluGNKgOey8GEzCTgmgCKhmCoQSB0FMVg0oJYEPIiD8AA2KBpCmsK2CGCGk3QEBIkEoHoC4AAG90AIAIAMcxhKB4BBAIBXqABfPQD6iAJEJwH6v6gG4G0GjTTQCQf6gAbVBs-ves-vRqoBYH-qsBBoxs-vfzwAQGeoQCRu4AUBpG4D0B4FAHBCsUpp4FYHpu4AM2AFwGYAkCRG4AAF1ca8angiAMUkaUa8bEacaIAxaxbuBhNubea8aIBEb9A0AqbFapasgZbhbPqubhaYaMa0a8bWB_qhhZb0bklN0CIpADMJBkrekxhsbjbPrjiKp0oX9sB_q9a5aOa3D_rmaX8JBKaNb0b5NKRKA2A3aIACbcAib6BvbGaqaX9ekwBvaCBqBuAIBAaA706MbM6IAebQaDNmASAhaMbRAIBiQIBwQ2VOBhb3b0bPbcBvaK615_a5bG7cAEQ9p66AaA7PqNYWAJAfA7aM77aIB4AniLAPAkRsABFwR_qFEXTcBh7-AwB_RK63bu6IAKpZAnro6IA56DNh7PrW726vK165aMa6BwQX9vazh5iOBs1abcBm6z6e7WB-7DaD7a6npO7uBxBR7cAWBpNn6daz74BJ7p7vbqBKAwBRVH6P7QGp7aBwQPBsJO6hgcb17kgFAfACBfrT7n7w7fqQA1AvKsaIBjirF17gG5a4akb5bXqIA6B46kaxahgubgaAaGHaAmH5bFbWG06uac7h7s7PqqGIAS6CBLaIBddDA0Bq6A666G7K6n6Maj6OaT6u7n7e637xahHh7R7aBx6wHEHZ6QB57F7wAV6148G5bN7-Bt7YATGzH17VGO7rGz6FGeAngK6AGP7RGMb4Hp7kHthO6JI4GjHwREwpAJBO70Hn7wQiHcAZ6NH8H9GLB_ryGF7178bfqpBvpO6ABaIYAUD-z65ueAUmYm727AVgFgLy5Rs-rhMAOx6JxOngV6p6o0XAAAH2kbQEBvqblpLo0GoEmzABHlgBYHiEvtae4GIB8aydLvlVGfGcmcQavuSfwaoG03-poHoCYFYA4BKbTqOa0YHogFCYWcrxDtu3-ouc2eYEeLcefo6fUZrs2YUBABYHf2UCRsKeKZ0YBasC1s2ZEYWeEbxr8fRswewfKahreb5oQvUYyaOa4WoGgChuZrZsoBIAGbxvifYiSfhbltSfSZgEyc2chZUcruPs7qJbxtOf-uKYWc-ovvWe4GIbpqOfBazo_pofloWeRpBY2aFZHvCZ2fk0UyOZbupbUdpeZbPtZZmYImXoYAftxaFYZfOalYhe1YxuhZwbhflelbXhpaeZFZfr7rOaZfNblsVevosdVc5aNYhedZEd1cDq4bAFIcRtQCptYflcpbxrpefoCeMbk3oElddc4e4cRpuD9eBZBe5bxtzs2fXpTZdZ5dBq1sBpUHQHQEemCGwbAAkAADpLam17GAAKR64mgAShUCAA)

I set in markLine where is there 'ADV' text.

anyone have a workground to make it work ? thanks in advance

Comment: it's weird it works only with uri image:
image: 'https://echarts.apache.org/en/images/logo.png?_v_=20240226'
The doc tell its possible to add URI or base64 : https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markLine.label.backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

removed image:// from iconBridge it works [image]